# How to unit test code before await in async function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency

I'm new to using swift's modern concurrency, and still learning how it works. I have a following test case where I want to test `viewState` is equal to `.loading` when `getUsers()` function is called, but no idea how to do it.

```
  func testShouldShowLoadingViewWhileLoadingUsers() async {
    mocAPIClient.response = Users.stub
    await sut.getUsers()
    XCTAssertEqual(sut.viewState, .loading)
  }
```

```
@MainActor
  private func getUsers() async {
    self.viewState = .loading
    let result = await apiClient.getUsers()
    switch result {
    case .success(let response):
      self.viewState = .normal(users)
    case .failure(let error):
      self.viewState = .error(message: error.message)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Consider doing this as a UI Test.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to validate a side effect that happens during the async function execution. One approach to this would be to make use of the `apiClient` - I assume you already have a protocol over it that you can use to inject a test class instead of using the actual http client.

Thus, assuming your api client protocol looks like this:

```swift
protocol APIClient {
    func getUsers() async -> Result<[User], Error>
}
```

, then you can write a fake class that you can control from the unit test:

```swift
class TestAPIClient: APIClient {
    var getUsersImpl: () async -> Result<[User], Error> = { .failure(TestError.someError) }

    func getUsers() async -> Result<[User], Error> {
        await getUsersImpl()
    }
}
```

With the above setup in place, you can write your test like this:

```swift
func testShouldShowLoadingViewWhileLoadingUsers() async {
    var capturedViewState: ViewState?
    testAPIClient.getUserImpl = {
        // capture `viewState` at the moment the APIClient is called
        capturedViewState = sut.viewState
        return Users.stub
    }

    await sut.getUsers()

    XCTAssertEqual(capturedViewState, .loading)
}
```